# Assign Value to Empty Content in StringTokenizer

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

I have to read inputs from a file which consists of pipe delimetered strings

```
A|UK|2|1
B||3|1

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data,"|");

String id=st.nextToken();
String country=st.nextToken();
String count=st.nextToken();
String flag=st.nextToken();
```

for the second line of file,There is a empty content,i want to assign "" string if there is no content,how do i do this using nextToken?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to use split and it will work without any exceptions

```
String yourstring = "B||3|1";
String [] arr = yourstring.split("\\|");

String id=arr[0];
String country=arr[1];
String count=arr[2];
String flag=arr[3];
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution could be using the three parameter constructor

```
StringTokenizer(String str, String delim, boolean returnDelims)
```

passing `true` as the third parameter.
This way StringTokenizer gives you the delimiters as tokens, so you can check empty fields just checking two or more consecutive delimiters.